# How can I assign a value to an attribute of a form after the submit button is pressed

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, forms

I am trying to change the value of a form based on the user selecting null

```
<form name="myForm" action="formProcess.php" method='post' onSubmit="return validateForm()">
<label for="venue">Venue:</label>
   <select name="venue">
   <option value="null">Please choose</option>
   <option value="Wynyard Hall">Wynyard Hall</option>
   <option value="Home">Home</option>
   <option value="Hallgarth">Hallgarth</option>
   <option value="Other">Other</option>
</select>
```

Here is the function

```
function validateForm() {

var d=document.forms["myForm"]["venue"].value;
if (d=="null") {
```

Here is what I want to do.I want to change the value of venue to the users prompt. Something along the lines of:

```
var newVenue = prompt("Tell us your venue");
venue = newVenue;
```

I know this is wrong but this is my goal. I have used this code I found on here.

```
$('#myForm').submit(function() {
var txt = $('#venue');
txt.val([newVenue]);
});

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That code is looking for a DOM element with an id "venue". Just change it to look for an element with a name attribute = to "venue".

```
$('input[value="Hot Fuzz"]')

$('#myForm').submit(function() {
    var txt = $('select[name="venue"]');
    txt.val(//Your new value );
});
```

Please check the jQuery documentation.